# A Rust function to return an iterator over lines of a zipped file

Tags: rust

I found code for a function that returns an iterator over the lines of a text file:

```
pub fn read_file_iterator(path: &str) -> io::Result<Lines<BufReader<File>>> {
    let file = File::open(path)?;
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(file);
    // lines() returns an iterator over lines
    Ok(buf_reader.lines())
}
```

Having zero experience with Rust, I thought I could adopt this code for a file which is a part of a ZIP archive:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::{self, BufReader, Lines, Cursor};
use std::path::Path;
use zip::read::ZipFile;

pub fn read_zip_file(_filename: &Path) -> io::Result<Lines<BufReader<ZipFile>>> {
    let reader = Cursor::new(std::fs::read(_filename)?);

    let mut zip_archive = zip::ZipArchive::new(reader)?;

    assert_eq!(1, zip_archive.len());

    let zip_file: ZipFile = zip_archive.by_index(0).unwrap(); // E: `zip_archive` is borrowed here"

    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(zip_file);

    Ok(buf_reader.lines()) // E: returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
}
```

Building this code results in an error (see also the comments that reflect the error details):

> cannot return value referencing local variable `zip_archive`

What is the right way of writing such a function?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `read_zip_file` is doing much more than the `read_file_iterator` - `ZipFile` mutably *borrows* `zip_archive` which then goes out of scope. `ZipFile` does not exist without `ZipArchive`. This is not allowed, as the borrow checker suggested.

One approach would be to unzip this particular file as a temporary (as your ordinary zip browser does) and then do the iteration as in your first snippet. If the file is small and you know it beforehand - you better just collect the data, with e.g. [read_to_end](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end) which `ZipFile` implements.

Comment: Does it mean that it's possible to have `zip_archive` as a function parameter instead, in order to overcome the problem?